# Windows 10 Imaging and Configuration Designer error when trying to start a project

Tags: windows-10, deployment, adk

I'm trying to create a new image project following the directions from this link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn916105(v=vs.85).aspx

After clicking "Finish" on step 9, ICD prompts me with the error message in the screenshot below.

[image: ICD Error]

I've tried the same steps on multiple computers using Windows 10 and 7, both 32bit and 64bit.  I've also rebuilt my Win 10 media using the media creation tool.

I posted the same question on TechNet and was asked to check the ICD.log at c:\users[you user account]\Documents\Windows Imaging and Configuration Designer (WICD)[Project name].  I have multiple project folders from all of my attempts at creating new project.  Each folder has an empty 0KB ICD.log file.

So far I haven't received any advice passed that.  Are there any additional logs that would be useful to review?  Or should I not be using ICD at all?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into an issue with the antivirus that I had on my machine.  It was blocking dism.exe, and producing a similar error.  Perhaps try disabling AV?

Comment: Ty for the suggestion, hadn't thought about that yet but unfortunately most of my tests were done on systems with no av even installed.  They were fresh loads of Windows for troubleshooting.  I know my companies network is more locked down than average businesses so for grins I also tested several machines off site.

Comment: And as an added comment, I just realized windows defender would have been on.  I tried again with defender disabled with the same results.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using a release/version of Windows other than Enterprise,
upgrade to Enterprise.  (That fixed it for me.)